# Stream several audio clients with rtsp to wowza

Tags: audio, streaming, audio-streaming, rtsp, wowza

Is there any command line clients that are able to start several RTSP audio streams?, I'm looking to build a web application on top of it to control several radio stations, i have a perpetual wowza license but I need to find a proper client to create the audio streams, preferably one that you can pass a script to determine what song goes next and that is able to use an encoder like lame for lower bitrates.

Answer (score 0):

One possible pipeline is:

`FFmpeg (playlist + concat demuxer) RTSP --> Darwin Streaming Server or revmischa RTP server --> Wowza`